# Mongoose saving

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

`model.save()` confuses me a lot.

Example. i moved my `mongoose.model(mongoose.schema)` in separate `model.js` file. when i create models using this method the following bothers me.

How does save method find a connection which i established with db. 
Seconds if i have 2 instances of mondogDB connections, which one it picks ?

here is the schema

```
const Schema = require("mongoose").Schema;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

   const User = new Schema({
   name: String, 
   password: String, 

   date_created: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
   },

   authorized: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
   } 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", User);
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the output of `mongoose.model()` is a model, and a given model is always tied to one connection.

By default, most folks just use the connection and connection pooling available from `mongoose.connect()`.  Once you call that, the cached mongoose module is using a singleton connection object under the hood.  So for example, if I'm calling your model, I'd do this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./models/user');

mongoose.connect(); // or pass in a custom URL

// from here, User will default to the mongoose-internal connection created in the previous line
```

If I want to use multiple connections, I cannot use the mongoose internal singleton, so I would have to do the operations with the created connection.  For example:

```
// ./schemas/user.js
// You now export the Schema rather than the module in your file
//module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
module.exports = User;
```

Then in the calling code:

```
const config = require('./config'); // presumably this has a couple mongo URLs
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserSchema = require('./schemas/user');

const conn1 = mongoose.createConnection(config.url1);
const conn2 = mongoose.createConnection(config.url2);

const User1 = conn1.model('User', UserSchema);
const User2 = conn2.model('User', UserSchema);

// now any users created with User1 will save to the first db, users created with User2 will save to the second.
```

Comment: Sir, you saved my day. god bless you :)

Comment: Glad to be able to help.